# SQL Maintenance Tasks on Azure [Ola Hallengren Scripts]

Tags: azure-sql-database, ola-hallengren

I am trying to implement the SQL maintenance scripts from Ola on my Azure elastic pool databases. I did the steps as provided in [this link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5666/index-maintenance-in-azure-sql-database-with-ola-hallengrens-scripts-and-elastic-database-jobs/).

I could create the job, but I always get this error after running the job manually:
[image: Job Step skipped]

Does anybody have some experience with these maintenance tasks on Azure?

Comment: Is the job still running?

Comment: Hi @George.Palacios Thank you for the Tipp, i tried to stop all the jobs and start it again manually. Now i get another error: Command failed: User does not have permission to perform this action. _CREATE SCHEMA failed due to previous errors. Cannot find the schema 'Maintenance', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. (Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Line 1)'_ I am not sure, which user (master or user) i need to use when creating the elastic job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on that article, you are expected to create Hallengren schema and its related database objects on each database on the pool, instead of using the Master database to create the schema and objects. Steps 1 to 4 on that article tell you how to perform that setup using jobs.

After that the article shows you how to use Hallengren scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to recreate the job with all the jobsteps manually again (with the script provided [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/tipimages2/5666_Scripts.zip)!), and then reset the permissions on job-/target-databases. After that the job runs successfully. Thank you for your help!